# How to keep overlay ( including navbar, hero txt, cta ) fom breaking apart when setting position to fixed?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

This is a little hard to explain but here it is,
I'am trying to replicate teslas site...[enter link description here](https://www.tesla.com/)

**Goal**: and and my current roadblock is getting the navbar, headings, and buttons to overlay on top of the images in a fixed position while being able to scroll down the other images.

**Problem**: Every time i give the overlay container a fixed position the it takes it from the center and gives a seemingly undefind width.I try to counteract this by giving the container a width and margin: 0 auto; but it does nothing.

- when i hover my mouse over anything in between the overlay i cant scroll through the images.

[image: CODE]

[image]

Comment: Please use code, not images, and give the fixed part 100vw width and 100vh , maybe?

Comment: @Rmaxx that was it thank you, however still if my mouse is anywhere over the overlay i cant scroll through imgs, would you know a fix?

Comment: Im not going tobretype your cod eto figure it out, but the fixed overlay shouldnt effect your page ability to scroll. Try the bg part in a seperate file and you might see the problem..

Answer (score 2):

> Every time i give the overlay container a fixed position the it takes it from the center and gives a seemingly undefind width.I try to counteract this by giving the container a width and margin: 0 auto; but it does nothing.

Apply these rules to the container, and then use your `margin: 0 auto;`:

```
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

That should let you center the container.